# Multi level micro price

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency, market-microstructure, market-making, limit-order-book

Typical micro price formula uses the top of book depth (i.e. level 1 depth):

> Microprice = (BidSize x AskPrice + AskSize x BidPrice) / (BidSize + AskSize)

But how does one actually include more depth levels (e.g. top 3 levels)?

> Multi-level Microprice = (TotalBidSize x AskVwapPrice + BidVwapPrice x TotalAskSize) / (TotalBidSize + TotalAskSize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive way of doing it: weight each price by the depth of the opposing side.

$$\text{p}\left(n\right){\displaystyle =}\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(s_{b,i}p_{a,i}+s_{a,i}p_{b,i}\right)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(s_{b,i}+s_{a,i}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to tinker with more variants of such prices to figure out what would be my fair value mid given an orderbook and been seeing a lot of this microprice.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind this is only one functional form. There's other ways of formulating multi-level microprice.